# How to duplicate logic of both @Type and @Convert in Hibernate when mapping PostgreSQL enum?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, enums

I have an existing PostgreSQL database with an entity called `Bike`, with a field `bike_gear_value` whose type is an enum `bike_gear` with values `GEAR-ONE`, `GEAR-TWO`. I *cannot* change the database table.

The problem I'm having is mapping a Java enum to that existing enum in the db. I am using Hibernate and querying/saving the Bike entity using Spring Boot's repository interface.

Here is my enum in Java (keeping in mind you can't have enum values with dashes),

```java
public enum BikeGear {
    GEARONE("GEAR-ONE"),
    GEARTWO("GEAR-TWO");

    //constructors, getters, setters

    public static BikeGear fromCode(String code){
        for (BikeGear bike : BikeGear.values()) {
            if(bike.getValue().equals(code)){
                return bike;
            }
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                "The code " + code + " is not supported!"
        );
    }
}
```

I have an AttributeConverter,

```java
@Converter
public class BikeGearConverter implements AttributeConverter<BikeGear, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(BikeGear attribute) {
        if(attribute == null){
            return null;
        }
        return attribute.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public BikeGear convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        if(dbData == null){
            return null;
        }
        return BikeGear.fromCode(dbData);
    }
}
```

I have a PostgreSQLEnumType class,

```java
public class PostgreSQLEnumType extends org.hibernate.type.EnumType {

    public void nullSafeSet(
            PreparedStatement st,
            Object value,
            int index,
            SharedSessionContractImplementor session)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        st.setObject(
                index,
                value != null ?
                        ((Enum) value).name() :
                        null,
                Types.OTHER
        );
    }
}
```

Lastly, here is my Bike class (simplified),

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "bike")
@TypeDef(
        name = "pgsql_enum",
        typeClass = PostgreSQLEnumType.class
)
public class Bike {
    @Column(name = "bike_gear_value")
    // @Type(type = "pgsql_enum")
    // @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    // @Convert(converter = BikeGearConverter.class)
    BikeGear rating;

    //constructors, getters, setters
}
```

Here are the errors I get using the following combinations of `@Type` (w/ `@TypeDef`), `@Enumerated` and `@Convert`,

@Type and @Convert

```java
AttributeConverter and explicit Type cannot be applied to same attribute
```

@Convert and @Enumerated

```java
// Saving a Bike
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "bike_gear_value" is of type bike_gear but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

// Querying a Bike
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.example.bikeapp.model.BikeGear.GEAR-ONE
```

@Convert

```java
// Saving a Bike
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "bike_gear_value" is of type bike_gear but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

// Querying a Bike
Successful
```

@Type

```java
// Saving a Bike
Successful

// Querying a Bike
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.example.bikeapp.model.BikeGear.GEAR-ONE
```

Ideally I would use @Type and @Converter so that both saving and querying is successful, however that's not allowed. Does anyone have recommendations here for a solution?

Comment: Can you show us Database column  defination.

Comment: Column definition in Bike table, `bike_gear_value public.bike_gear DEFAULT 'GEAR-ONE'::public.bike_gear`. Enum definition, `CREATE TYPE public.bike_gear AS ENUM (
    'GEAR-ONE',
    'GEAR-TWO'
);
`

Comment: Use `columnDefinition` like  `@Column(name = "bike_gear_value", columnDefinition = "enum('GEAR-ONE', 'GEAR-TWO')")`

Comment: Which combination of annotations do I use between `@Enumerated`, `@Type` and `@Convert`?

Comment: Just use @Convert and column defination

Comment: I still get the same error when saving a Bike, `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "bike_gear_value" is of type bike_gear but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.`

Comment: That should work or try to use @Type add `nullSafeGet` to fetch properly https://gist.github.com/jedvardsson/96af1b86f78762ac12ef#file-labeledenumtype-java-L49

Comment: Overriding nullSafeGet worked (didn't need columnDefinition), thanks

Comment: columnDefinition needed when use @Convert. finally it's working